# getting an error while performing a lookup and what will be a better way to do the same

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a lookup to detect outliers in my observation data frame. lookup data frame, df_ref, is rather small (approximately 50 rows) and the observation data frame is around 200,000 rows. The following code explains the sample data and my approach:

```
df_ref = data.frame(id = c(2, 7, 12), ref = c(15, 27, 32))
df_obs = data.frame(obs = rep(11, 4), val = c(3, 4, 7, 13))
```

The lookup is based on the following logic (data is coded in df_ref.

```
if val >= 2 and val < 7 then ref = 15 
if val >= 7 and val < 12 then ref = 27 
if val >= 12 then ref = 32
```

I want to add a column ref_val in df_obs determined based on above logic using val in df_val and (id, ref) of df_ref.

The following R function does the lookup correctly

```
get_ref = function(x, df_ref) {
    df_ref[df_ref$id == max(df_ref$id[x >= df_ref$id]), "val"]
}
```

When I use this function on df_obs, like

```
mutate(df_obs, ref=get_ref(val, df_ref))

I get the following error:

  obs val
1  11   3
2  11   4
3  11   7
4  11  13
Warning message:
In x >= df_ref$id :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

The final output should look like

```
df_obs

  obs val  ref
1  11   3   15
2  11   4   15
3  11   7   27
4  11  13   32
```

What am I doing wrong here? And What will be a better R-ish way to accomplish this lookup? Please help.

regards

K

Comment: It seems like `cut` would be helpful here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing `df_obs$val` with `df_ref$id` and R warns you that they are not of equal length and it might do something you don't expect, i.e., it recycles the shorter vector.

I would do a rolling join with data.tables:

```
library(data.table)
dt_ref <- data.table(df_ref, key = "id")
dt_obs <- data.table(df_obs, key = "val")

dt_ref[dt_obs, roll = TRUE]

#    id ref obs
# 1:  3  15  11
# 2:  4  15  11
# 3:  7  27  11
# 4: 13  32  11
```

Comment: This seems very convenient. Will have to look into this some more. +1

Comment: This definitely is a much better solution. One thing I noticed that the key column name of dt_obt table is replaced by key column of dt_ref ("val" as "id") above. Is there any way I can retain the actual column name without resorting to colnames.

Comment: I don't know a way. But you could simply rename the column in the look-up table. And don't use `colnames<-` with data.tables. Use `dt_new <- setnames(dt_ref[dt_obs,roll=T], "id", "val")`.

Answer (score 1):

`cut` might be of interest here (but its syntax sometime take some playing around with to become comfortable with it).

```
cut(df_obs$val, 
    breaks = c(df_ref$id, Inf), 
    labels = df_ref$ref, 
    right = FALSE)
# [1] 15 15 27 32
# Levels: 15 27 32
```

The output is a `factor`, and if you needed it as `numeric`, you'll have to do `as.numeric(as.character(...))`.